# Cannot import name 'ClientWithProject'

Tags: google-cloud-storage, python-3.6

I am trying to run my script for downloading file from google cloud storage bucket to my local directory and I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "ingest/tasks/download_feeds.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.cloud import datastore, storage
  File "/Users/manelrhaiem/liqid-marketing-pipeline/yoda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from google.cloud.storage.client import Client
  File "/Users/manelrhaiem/liqid-marketing-pipeline/yoda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.cloud.client import ClientWithProject
ImportError: cannot import name 'ClientWithProject'
```

it looks like the error more related to the library itself, here my `pip freeze | grep google` result:

```
gapic-google-logging-v2==0.9.3
gapic-google-pubsub-v1==0.9.3
google-api-core==1.3.0
google-auth==1.5.1
google-cloud==0.19.0
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-logging==1.6.0
google-cloud-storage==1.6.0
google-gax==0.13.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
grpc-google-logging-v2==0.9.3
grpc-google-pubsub-v1==0.9.3
```

I think it might be related to some compatible versions but I am not sure about it yet.

Looking forward to your help

Comment: It's a weird error, but, to proceed in the debugging, do you actually have `google-cloud-datastore` installed? I've seen that you have tried to import it, but it's not appearing in your installed packages. Try to install/update both Storage and Datastore with `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore google-cloud-storage`.